# C language unnecessary repetition

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a C program to calculate some factorial ,square, etc. I'm using function to display a menu to the user that has a problem when the user types a wrong character the programs warms the user using the warning message two times.

What I have to change in order to display only once the menu of options after the user types a wrong character? Thanks

Here is the result I have : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpC9b.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ACTION "Enter a number inside the range specified above:"

// Function declaration

void factorialeven();
void factorialodd();
void square();
void cube();
void fifthpower();
void mainmenu();
void secondmenu();

int main()
{
    int y = 1;
    char q;
    mainmenu();
    while (y)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s", ACTION);

        q = getchar();
        // reading user input and assign it to variable q

        switch (q)
        {
        case '1':
            factorialeven();
            break;

        case '2':
            factorialodd();
            break;

        case '3':
            square();
            break;

        case '4':
            cube(); // option 4 for cube
            break;  // End case 4

        case '5':
            fifthpower(); // option 5 for 5th power
            break;  // End case 5

        case '6':
            exit(0);
            break;  // End case 6

        default:    // catch all other options
            /*telling the user that the input is invalid */
            printf("\n**********You have entered unavailable option");
            printf("***********\n");
            printf("\n*****Please Enter any one of below available 
      options****\n ");
            secondmenu();
            // displaying the menu without header
        }       // End switch
    }               // End while
}                   // End main

// Function definitions
void mainmenu()                 // Menu of selection
{
    printf("\n---------- Welcome to our Project 1 ---------- \n");
    printf("\nPress 1 to calculate Factorials for Even Numbers");
    printf(" between 2 and 16\n");
    printf("\nPress 2 to calculate Factorials for Odd Numbers");
    printf(" between 1 and 15\n\n");
    printf("Press 3 to calculate the Square of number between -14 
      and 14\n\n");
    printf("Press 4 to show the Cube of numbers between -14 and 
      14\n\n");
    printf("Press 5 to show Fifth Power numbers between -12 and 
      12\n\n");
    printf("--------- Press '6' to quit ");
    printf("the program ---------\n");
}

void secondmenu()
{
    printf("\nPress 1 to calculate Factorials for Even Numbers");
    printf(" between 2 and 16\n\n");
    printf("\nPress 2 to calculate Factorials for Odd Numbers");
    printf(" between 1 and 15\n\n");
    printf("Press 3 to calculate the Square of number between -14 and 14\n\n");
    printf("Press 4 to show the Cube of numbers between -14 and 14\n\n");
    printf("Press 5 to show Fifth Power numbers between -12 and 12\n\n");
    printf("--------- Press '6' to quit ");
    printf("the program ---------\n");
}               // End function

int fact(int b)
{
    if (b <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return b * (fact(b - 1));
    }
}

void factorialeven()
{
    int t = 0;
    printf("\nEven numbers\tFactorials\n");
    while (t <= 15)
    {
        t += 2;
        printf("%d\t\t%d\n", t, fact(t));   // Displays the results
    }               // End while
}               // End function

void factorialodd()
{
    int r = 17;
    printf("\nOdd numbers\tFactorials\n");
    while (r >= 2)
    {
        r -= 2;
        printf("%d\t\t%d\n", r, fact(r));
    }
}

void square()
{
    int g = 15;
    int square;
    printf("\nNumbers\t\tSquare\n");
    while (g >= -13)
    {
        g -= 1;
        square = pow(g, 2);
        printf("%d\t\t%d\n", g, square);
    }
}

void cube()
{
    int h = -15;
    int cube;
    printf("\nNumbers\t\tCube\n");
    while (h <= 13)

    {
        h += 1;
        cube = pow(h, 3);
        function printf("%d\t\t%d\n", h, cube);
    }
}

void fifthpower()
{
    int l = -13;
    int fifthpower;
    printf("\nNumbers\t\tFifth Power\n");
    while (l <= 11)
    {
        l += 1;         // Increases the counter by 2
        fifthpower = pow(l, 5);
        printf("%d\t\t%d\n", l, fifthpower);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why your prompt string is set up the way it is. Why use printf ("%s", ACTION); with ACTION defined in the pre-processor rather than just putting the string you want in a printf statement directly? I could see this perhaps being useful if you reuse the string several times but in a cursory glance I only see one use. Furthermore it would be more concise to just write printf(ACTION) or even better puts(ACTION).

Comment: Include the output in the question, formatted as text, not as a link to an image.

Comment: @psychedelic_alex: `printf(ACTION)` is dangerous if there's any possibility that `ACTION` could include a `%` character. `puts(ACTION)` is not equivalent, since it appends a newline character. `fputs(ACTION, stdout)` would work, but there's nothing particularly wrong with `printf("%s", ACTION)`.

Comment: You're right. It's better to put directly the string into the printf. I did that and I'm still having the same repetition. I type a wrong character and the menu repeats two times. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to put q as an integer and then use scanf but when a letter is typed the menu is displayed infinetely.

Comment: @guasabito: No, it's not better to put the string directly into the `printf`; see my previous comment.

Comment: Note that although you have some function declarations, you have no function prototypes — except for function `fact()` where the definition does include a prototype.  The functions taking no argument need to be declared explicitly with `void function_name(void);` — the `(void)` is crucial.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add void to every function and still is doing the same repetition. Any other idea? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Thanks  @KeithThompson I followed what you said.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I wouldn't quite call it "crucial" (old-style function declarations are still valid), but it's certainly a good idea, and there's rarely if ever a good reason to declare a function with `()` rather than `(void)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson — the parenthesized `void` is crucial to making the declaration into a prototype.   Although the standard still permits the non-prototype declarations, they have been marked as obsolescent by the future directions clause since C89 was published.  In this day and age, you should not use non-prototype function declarations or definitions.  I actually do regard it as crucial that people learning C learn good habits, and writing non-prototype functions is an extremely bad habit.  Maybe it was excusable in 1992; it is not excusable in 2018.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree *almost* entirely. One thing to consider is that compilers will probably not complain about non-prototype function declarations, so "but the compiler didn't complain and it worked!" is a likely response. And assuming the calls in the OP's program are correct, changing `()` to `(void)` would produce no change in behavior. (They've been "obsolescent" for way too long IMHO.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: "Way too long" — yes, though I'm still fighting to get some code upgraded too.  Both GCC and Clang (if only for compatibility with GCC) have options that effectively demand prototypes.  Permutations of `-Wmissing-prototypes` , `-Wstrict-prototypes`, `-Wold-style-definitions`, and `-Wold-style-declarations` (depending on compiler and version) in conjunction with `-Wall` (and preferably `-Wextra` and `-Werror`) do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program prompts for a single character and reads it using `getchar()` (which returns an `int`, not a `char`, so `q` needs to be define as an `int` and checked for equality to `EOF`).

If you enter an incorrect character (say, `'x'`), you're actually entering *two* characters: the `'x'` and a newline when you type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It takes two `getchar()` calls to read them both, so you get two error messages.

If the input is meant to be line-oriented you can read a line into a string using `fgets()` (but handling input longer than your target array is tricky), or you can read a single character and then read and discard characters up to a `'\n'` or `EOF`.

Comment: How can I discard that extra character that I'm typing, or can I just add something to the code so it can automatically press enter when a character is typed.

Comment: @guasabito You could discard input with a loop like this: `{ int c; while (c = getchar(), c != EOF && c != '\n') {} }`

Comment: Sorry to ask, I'm 13 years old and this is tricky for me, but your help is really appreciated.

Comment: @KeithThompson I fix it! I used scanf(" %c",&q); and it worked perfectly. Thanks .

Comment: @guasabito: I think that's because `scanf` skips white space (including new-lines).

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks Very Much